# Reattaching screen (having irssi running) forces window resize

Tags: putty, gnu-screen, irssi

Whenever I reattach to my detached screen (containing Irssi), my Putty screen is resized to something it has been at startup. If I change the window size after this, detach the screen and resize it back, window will be again resized to the original size. By window I mean the Putty window on my windows box. How can I turn this feature off?

Using Windows XP as my local and CentOS 6.0 as the remote OS. Putty 0.61.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also prevent screen from resizing any remote sessions. The other answer prevents this in your one local putty installation - but what if you come to another workstation?

Anyway, to prevent screen from resizing xterms, you need to:

- Edit `/etc/screenrc`
- Find this this bit of text

---

```
# Long time I had this in my private screenrc file. But many people
# seem to want it (jw):
# we do not want the width to change to 80 characters on startup:
# on suns, /etc/termcap has :is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;3;4;6l:

#termcap xterm 'is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l'
#terminfo xterm 'is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l'
```

---

- Uncomment those two termcap lines and screen will behave from now on.

I just ran into this problem, googled, found the answer [here](http://systemsandsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/06/preventing-screen-from-resizing-xterm.html), tested and thought it might be useful for others.

Note that if you are unable or do not want to edit the global screenrc configuration, `~/.screenrc` will do just fine for your current user.

Comment: I'd be tempted to mark this as the accepted answer but it seems I'm unable to test it as the behaviour went away... Have to upvote at least though :)

Comment: Yes! managed to test it now and works exactly like described.

Comment: glad it worked for ya :)

Comment: pmodin's comment on the original site fixed this answer in my case: I had to set it as "xterm*" as my putty configuration uses xterm-color as TERM.

Comment: not working for me.  cant get to resize, using 4.02.01
im also trying to launch with screen -AR, or any combo of screen -Ar, and initial launch with screen works fine, and intial launch of screen -A works fine, any detachment breaks it.  also have this on .screenrc which is supposed to fake it, and no go. `escape ^a` followed by  `bindkey ^ad detach`

Answer (score 13):

Found the answer. The feature is called "remote terminal resizing", and it can be disabled at Configuration -> Terminal -> Features -> Disable remote-controlled terminal resizing, as described in [PuTTY configuration](http://www.cs.kuleuven.be/system/security/ssh/introduction/putty/doc/Chapter4.html#S4.6.3).

Don't really know why reattaching screen does window resize remote request, though.

Comment: This worked well for me. I have a termcapinfo line in my .screenrc that forwards the scrollback buffer. I don't understand how the termcapinfo line is parsed and don't want to mess with it.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer lacks an explanation for the phenomena.  Here is one:

- The long string for `is` is an initialization string for the terminal, which usually is the same as `rs` (used by `reset`).
- The example given contains a control sequence which resets the terminal from 132 to 80 columns.  Just that part is the "3" in `\E[?1;3;4;6l`, which could be split up into four controls.  The one that affects the width is `\E[?3l` (see [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) for `"132 Column Mode (DECCOLM)"`).
- That happens to be a VT100 sequence, which was used in the [X11R5 xterm](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-r5) terminal description.
- When screen starts (or attaches), it initializes the terminal, just in case.  That changes the terminal's width.
- CentOS 6 is a little old now; the current upstream `xterm` description has used a shorter sequence for quite a while, which initializes more things.
- The newer/shorter sequence looks like this: `is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>` (defined in [`xterm-basic`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-basic)).  The `\E[!p` part is `DECSTR`, which resets character sets, color and video attributes.  The older sequence did not do that; telling `screen` to use it works, but is not as clean.
- If you use a different `TERM` setting, then the customization in `.screenrc` will have no effect (because it uses `TERM` to match the particular setting).
- In particular, if you use something like [`xterm-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-256color), you may notice the same behavior again.